# Correlation between variables in multiple files

Tags: r

I have 280 *.csv files in a directory. Each file has 3 columns and 1000 rows. I want to estimate Pearson's correlation between column 2 and 3 of each file and put the correlation value in the first cell of column 4, and also all 280 correlation values in a separate file. How can I do this in R?

I have tried several codes including the one below which although I know is incorrect, I do not know how to write. Please help.

```
files <- list.files(path="mydirectory", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE, 
recursive=FALSE)
function(files)
lapply(files,function(x){
  x <- read.csv(files, header = TRUE)
   out <- function(cor(files[,2:3])
    write.csv(out, sep = "\t", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the first part, that's easy. You can calculate the correlations in an lapply loop and write them to a new file:

```r
lapply(files, function(f) {
  # Read CSV data
  csv_data <- read.csv(f, header=TRUE)
  # Calculate correlation
  csv_data[, 4] <- cor(csv_data[, 2], csv_data[, 3])
  # Create a new filename by replacing the ending of the 
  # input file (.csv) with (_cor.csv)
  newfile <- gsub("\\.csv$", "_cor.csv", f)
  write.csv(csv_data, file = newfile, quote = FALSE)
})
```

Since R wants columns in data.frames to have the same number of rows, this will fill every row of the 4th column with the correlation value. I would roll with this, but if you have a lot of data this can waste storage. Here's a not very elegant solution to only have the correlation in the first row:

```r
lapply(files, function(f) {
  # Read CSV data
  csv_data <- read.csv(f, header=TRUE)
  # Calculate correlation
  csv_data[, 4] <- cor(csv_data[, 2], csv_data[, 3])
  # Now delete duplicate values of cor
  csv_data[2:nrow(csv_data), 4] <- NA
  # Create a new filename by replacing the ending of the 
  # input file (.csv) with (_cor.csv)
  newfile <- gsub("\\.csv$", "_cor.csv", f)
  # Now when we write, we tell R to write an empty string when it encounters
  # missing values
  write.csv(csv_data, file = newfile, quote = FALSE, na = "")
})
```

Also:
You do not need to call `function()` when you use functions that already exist (like `lapply()` or `cor()`). You only need to use that when you want to define a new function yourself.

If you want to have the output in a single `data.frame` try:

```r
my_df <- do.call(rbind,
  lapply(files, function(f) {
    # Read CSV data
    csv_data <- read.csv(f, header=TRUE)
    # Calculate correlation
    data.frame(File=f, Correlation=cor(csv_data[, 2], csv_data[, 3]))
  })
)
```

Comment: this was amazing, exactly what I needed. Thank you so very much.

Comment: If this solved your question please accept the answer so it doesn't show in open questions. Thanks!

Comment: How can I get the correlation values of all 280 samples in one file with each row having the cor value of one file?

Comment: I was thinking about doing all of it manually which would have taken me at least one month because I have several such files, this is just one. I don't know how to thank you enough. Best wishes!!